# How to place socket.io and http servers in different processes but using the same host and port?

Tags: node.js, scalability, socket.io

Most of the examples on the web offer something like this:

```
var app = require('express').createServer()
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(80);
```

which requires you to have both the http and the socket server to be in the same process.

If one is making a web site with some size to it, one may want to separate the two servers, but still have them use the same domains and ports. How would one go about that?

Comment: Do you literally mean they would be on separate servers? Or did you mean separate the two `services`? That would vastly affect the answer. Have you considered that splitting the processes is possibly not that useful and contrary to the whole spirit of node.js? If there are specific blocking/time-eating tasks, why not farm those instead of dealing with two processes trying to listen on a single port, and setting up some forward to make that possible?

Comment: @Kato, I was thinking about being more specific, but decided against it. How vast is the difference? Would you elaborate further on the spirit of node.js as it relates to this question? It seems to me that a separation of concerns, namely one of serving files, and another one of serving data is essential for a single thread architecture of node.

Comment: Well, there's some ambiguity between node's ideal view of using a single thread for everything and the fact that multiple threads can take better advantage of modern dual/quad/googleplex processors. But essentially, as I grok the approach, use one thread for everything, unless an operations would be overly long and simultaneously blocking.  Honestly, I don't feel really qualified to assess your approach, or speak on behalf of node's design; I was simply suggesting some prompts to inspire big-picture evaluation on your part :)

Comment: Thanks for your input. As I see it, the difference between php's approach and that of node is that php uses one thread for everything, but gives one to each client. Node gives one thread to each concern and one to all clients. But this is just theory, in practice the requirements are dictated by the details of the situation, as you have mentioned.

Comment: When called from Apache, PHP gets a new thread with each call. When called from the command line, PHP gets a new thread with each call. There is no PHP listener per se, unless you count the apache process as a connection pool and listener. Node uses an approach more like [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main), which does not start a separate thread for each process or call (Node/nginx is asynchronous, but not multi-threaded), which is surprisingly fast and light on resources.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly let me help clarify your question.

What you would wish to do is have both a NodeHTTP Web-server and SocketIO Client running on separate machines but still able to be accessed via same domain (not-subdomain)

This is going to be very hard and tricky, you will require multiple IP's to that box and haproxy to map requests accordingly

*If it's load balancing you need read about my stack:*

I have several servers (5 infact) that are load balanced via a round robin, so I have this in my DNS Records

```
relay.domain.com: {
    A : 10.0.0.1,
    A : 10.0.0.2,
    A : 10.0.0.3,
    A : 10.0.0.4
}
```

I Also have a master server located at *master.domain.com (10.0.0.0)*, all connections from my socket.io clients come on *relay.domain.com* and the connections are load balanced to the 4 servers.

each of the 4 servers are listing for connections on port 80, but they all create a *socket.io-client* connection to the master server and send all request to the master, the master then handles the socket data and if its data to be announce out we send that data back to all relay servers, which in turn announce to there client lists.

Comment: thanks for that, it doesn't quite answer the question, but I'm sure it can be useful